# Official name for iOS bar which notifies web browser of native app

Tags: ios, notification, toolbar

Super simple question (I think) - does anyone know what the official term is for the non-intrusive apple bar which notifies a user of an available app to use natively on their phone?

For an example, head to linkedin.com on your phone.

Comment: I call it 'an annoyance'

Comment: I found the answer.  It's a "Smart App Banner" [link] https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: Might be a good idea to make sure you mark the question as answered (even though you found the answer yourself) so it doesn't clog up the 'Unanswered' section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.  It's a "Smart App Banner" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html